# Artificial Intelligence and First Order Logic

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

I am undecided when to use universal quantifier or existential quantifier.
Here is my example:
Anyone passing his history exams and winning the lottery is happy.
In first order logic :
∀x Pass(x,history) ^ win(x,lottery) -> happy(x)
or 
∃x Pass(x, history) ^ win(x,lottery) -> happy(x)
I would like to know if the logic is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You should understand that both existential and universal quantifiers are **complements** of each other (similar to plus/minus and multiplication/division). Any can be achieved by negating the other one.

> Anyone passing his history exams and winning the lottery is happy.

The answers would be:

1. ∀x {Pass(x,history) ^ win(x,lottery) -> happy(x)}
   Read as: For all x, if x passes history and x wins lottery, then x is happy.
2. ~∃x {Pass(x, history) ^ win(x,lottery) -> ~happy(x)}
   Read as: It is **not the case** (or it is impossible) that if a person passes history and wins lottery, then he is not happy.

Comment: Good addition to this question giving a deeper understanding of the logic behind the two quantifiers!

Answer (score 3):

The existential quantifier would mean that "there is a person, X, such that ...", not "any person, X, such that".

Not sure why you have a "prolog" tag. But the corresponding clause in Prolog would be:

```
happy(X) :- pass(X, history), win(X, lottery).
```

Comment: Well thank you, but when there is the word anyone in the text, show I use existential ?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on the sentence that you want to express using first-order logic. A complex sentence can require multiple universal and multiple existential quantifiers.